# Cakephp: Utilizing my appcontroller to do a count of registrants with a specific role ID

Tags: php, cakephp

I am currently trying to display a user count on my website that only counts users with a certain role ID in my user database. So far I have tried several variations, but in continuously outputs the master count as opposed to the specific role count.

```
$this->set('fillme',$fillme);
        $coptions = array('conditions' => array('User.role_id' => 3));
        $students=      $this->User->find('count');
        $this->set('students',$students);
```

I'm not sure exactly what I'm doing wrong, I'll admit that I'm fairly new to Cakephp and all, but I've tried a few variations such as replacing '=>' with '==' or segregating ''User.role_id'' into ''User','role_id'' but none of it seems to work. Any and all help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did a little bit more research on the matter with an associated thread that was for a search function but I thought since it was based on the same sort of variables I could garner something from that. I changed the following and received an error...

    $students=     $this->User->find('count');

to

    $students=     $this->User->find('role_id','COUNT('User.role_id');

Comment: you should add your options array as second argument, $this->User->find('count', $coptions) and inside that array include more options regarding the query you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$this->set('fillme',$fillme);
$students = $this->User->find('count', array('conditions' => array('User.role_id' => 3));
$this->set('students',$students);
```

Note that I'm passing an array with the 'conditions' key in the find() function. Also see, http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html for more on how to retrieve your data and all the available options.

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you SO much!

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is [CakePHP's "counterCache"](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#countercache-cache-your-count).

The basic idea is, it automatically keeps track of how many of an associated model there are.

So in your case, you'd have a `user_count` field and in your `roles` table, then in your association, you tell it you want counterCache:

```
class User extends AppModel {
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Role' => array(
            'counterCache' => true,
        )
    );
}
```

From there, you can get the data easily at any point and pass it to your view:

```
$this->Role->id = $yourRoleId;
$students = $this->Role->field('user_count');
$this->set('students', $students);
```

This will keep you from having to do a count every time you query (should be caching anyway, but you get the idea).

Any time a user is added or deleted using CakePHP's `delete()`, `save()`, or `saveAll()`, it will automatically update the count in the field for you!